# How can i pass $_GET to another php via ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im going to make a kind of explanation about my problem:
Trying to integrate fullcalendar on a web that takes data via mysql & ajax, i want to display booking dates on calendar only if its related with one "house" in particular when this one is clicked.
So, in my php i receive $pisoid = $_GET['piso']; then i use in the same page a js script and i pass that data via post ajax:

```
    var pisoid = "<?php echo $pisoid; ?>" ;

$.ajax({
    url: 'process.php',
    type: 'POST', // Send post data
    data: 'type=fetch',
    async: false,
    success: function(s){
        json_events = s;
    }
});
```

Also i use this:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: JSON.parse(json_events),
        //events: [{"id":"14","title":"New Event","start":"2015-01-24T16:00:00+04:00","allDay":false}],
        utc: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        droppable: true, 
        slotDuration: '00:30:00',
        eventReceive: function(event){
            var title = event.title;
            var start = event.start.format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:SS");
            $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php',
                data: 'type=new&title='+title+'&startdate='+start+'&zone='+zone+'&pisoid='+pisoid,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    event.id = response.eventid;
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
                },
                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e.responseText);

                }
            });
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent',event);
            console.log(event);
        });
```

Then, on my process.php i try to make:

```
$space = $_POST['pisoid'];
$events = array();

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM calendar where pisoid='$space'");
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
$e = array();
$e['id'] = $fetch['id'];
$e['title'] = $fetch['title'];
$e['start'] = $fetch['startdate'];
$e['end'] = $fetch['enddate'];

$allday = ($fetch['allDay'] == "true") ? true : false;
$e['allDay'] = $allday;

array_push($events, $e);
}
echo json_encode($events);
```

Where i put a number instead of $space in my sql query everythings its ok, but in this $space i dont receive a proper number, So how can i make this stuff???

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: do any of the other variables get passed through to the script via ajax properly? Maybe the problem is how you are setting/getting the pisoid variable

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the data as if it was a URL in the fullcalendar function
Change this:

```
data: 'type=new&title='+title+'&startdate='+start+'&zone='+zone+'&pisoid='+pisoid,
```

To:

```
data: {type: 'new', title: title, startdate: start, zone: zone, pisoid: pisoid}
```

Like this you're passing different variables (type, title, etc...) To the superglobal you're using in the PHP file.

Explanation:
The data array is constructed as such: 'nameofattribute': variable
And JavaScript will take care of creating the URL/posting the data

Your problem is that you're trying to get the "GET" parameters of the data you're passing (without a key might I add) with the POST variable. Try switching them around, it should help

Comment: doesn't usually matter. jquery will accept a string or array/object, and convert the array/object to basically the same string anyways.

Comment: simpler using object...but results won't differ

Comment: To "basically" you can't be exactly sure if this, and it could actually solve the problem as he's passing a "GET" URL to a PHP script that uses "POST"

Comment: FMAshiro i have changed as you said butis not ok,  not render even my calendar...

Comment: @AlfonsoDelRio do you mind posting any errors? Console or PHP? And try to add `var_dump($_POST); to the top of your process.php

Comment: Apparently i dont have errors but still even dont render calendar. Thx so much for ur interest and help

Comment: @AlfonsoDelRío Did you try using the var_dump($_POST); as I mentionned?

Comment: @AlfonsoDelRío Could you try giving me the results of that var_dump ? it should print a lot of information

Comment: ive been trying to show my var_dump bit i cant...im getting crazy. sorry about my ignorance...but is strange because in the same away i can insert all datas properly so in $_POST['pisoid'] i am receiving a number but for "select" in sql on the same way os not working

Comment: At the end of process.php, add `echo json_encode($_POST);` and in the calendar .js in the success function add `alert(message)`

Comment: FMashiro can i pass u these 2 files and u check why is not working? i think i cant manage this

Comment: too long for pasting

Comment: Pastebin.com, try putting them there

Comment: if you are using google chrome, please press "F12", then go to the network tab, make the ajax event happen, click on the row that will be added, and select "preview", can you tell me what's in there? I can't run the code since I'm missing a lot of files and don't have the Database

Comment: I couldnt fix it.... i will follow fighting another day...im getting furious now jejej thanks so much for helping